# Handle NPE in Kotlin Flow For Room Database

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I want to **retrieve single object from Room** database, so i have this method in Dao

```
// in Dao
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_foo ORDER BY RANDOM()")
fun getSingleFoo(): Flow<FooEntity>
```

That object then will be mapped into others model, let say `PlainFoo`.

```
// in Repository
fun getRandomFoo(): Flow<PlainFoo> = dao.getSingleFoo()
        .map(FooEntity::asExternalModel)
```

But in the first launch of this app, the table is empty. It makes the dao function **return null and trigger NPE** when being mapped. I try to wrap it inside a sealed interface like this.

```
// Result.kt as wrapper
sealed interface Result<out T> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>
    data class Error(val exception: Throwable? = null) : Result<Nothing>
}

fun <T> Flow<T>.asResult(): Flow<Result<T>> = this
    .map<T, Result<T>> {
        Result.Success(it)
    }
    .catch {
        emit(Result.Error(it))
    }
```

And then i call this method in the presentation layer like this.

```
// in ViewModel
val randomFoo = fooRepository.getRandomFoo().asResult()

// in activity, log only for checking
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.randomFoo.collect {
        Timber.tag("RandomFooFlow").d("$it")
    }
}
```

It catches the error, which look like this.

```
Error(exception=java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter <this>)
```

But when new data is inserted, **it does not get updated** unless i reopen the app (which means new Flow is being collected, not the old one). So it seems that the flow is cancelled.

> Is there any way to handle this without making my Dao return a
> nullable object?

Note: if the data is already populated when opening the app, the flow is able to keep consuming new value).

Comment: Can I ask why don't you want to return nullable object from Dao? That's the most straightforward solution.

Comment: I've tried it and i think the mapping become a bit cumbersome and i have to return empty object for that

Comment: Why an empty object when you can return null from the mapping. `fun getRandomFoo(): Flow<PlainFoo?> = dao.getSingleFoo().map { it?.asExternalModel() }`

Comment: I actually dont want my repo to expose nullable value (just nitpick), but after tried it, i think it is good and straightforward as you say. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dealing with exceptions, I would suggest to return nullable types from your Dao. You can then also update your mapper function to handle the type nullability. You won't need to wrap it into any `Result` class, just a simple null check on the UI end would suffice.

```kotlin
// Dao
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_foo ORDER BY RANDOM()")
fun getSingleFoo(): Flow<FooEntity?>

// Repo
fun getRandomFoo(): Flow<PlainFoo?> = dao.getSingleFoo().map { it?.asExternalModel() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please call repository getRandomFoo() method from inside coroutine in view model ? And also you need to call response with data observe like LiveData or StateFlow. By the way, you can wrap your result with wrap inside repository. In code example, I do not care about it because your error is not related with mapping.

> View Model

```
private val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow()
val stateFlow:StateFlow

fun getRandom(){
    fooRepository.getRandomFoo().onEach{
       if(it is Result.Success){
           stateFlow.value = it
       }
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

> Fragment or activity

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle{ 
    stateFlow.collect{
        // Listen data for your UI
    }
}
```